# How to loop the video on mplayer with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: video, raspberry-pi, raspbian, lcd, mplayer

I'm currently trying to play a video clip using a Raspberry Pi with 3.5-inch touch display.
I know that omxplayer has the function to make it loop, but from some reason omxplayer can't play my video on 3.5inch LCD display. So I have only the option to use mplayer but I couldn't make it loop in mplayer so if you know how to make the video loop, please let me know.

Comment: Also: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

As it says in `man mplayer`:

> -loop
>
> Loops movie playback  times.  0 means forever.

So it should be:

```
mplayer -loop 0 <VIDEO>
```

If you ever come across a player that does not support looping you can
easily create such loop yourself:

```
while true; do <player> <video> ; done
```

Comment: Ok. You can now mark this [question as
answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to let
other users know your problem is solved.